# Removing button and load data

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Hey guys I need help with removing this button and load data from json file without need to click on that button
Here's code

```
List _items = [];
```

// Fetch content from the json file

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
Future readJson() async {
final String response =
await rootBundle.loadString('assets/aaaa.json');
final data = await json.decode(response);
setState(() {
_items = data['first'];
});
}

```
return Scaffold(
  body: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
    child: Column(
      children: [
        ElevatedButton(
          child: const Text('Load Data'),
          onPressed: readJson,
        ),
        // Display the data loaded from sample.json
        _items.isNotEmpty
            ? Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: _items.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Card(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: ListTile(
                        leading: Text(_items[index]["aaaaa"]),
                        title: Text(_items[index]["aaaaa"]),
                        subtitle: Text(_items[index]["aaaaaa"]),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              )
            : Container()
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

Comment: Please read the documentation of the tools your using before posting on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [Future Builder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).  There are some good examples on that page of how to use the widget, including how to show different widgets depending on if the data was loaded, is in the process of loading, or there was an error.  `readJson` would be the future in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Call **initState()** before build function

```
   @overrride
   initState() { 
      readJson();
      super.initState(); 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling the readJson() function just before returning Scaffold will do what you want.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //load the json content
    readJson();
    return Scaffold(
  body: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
    child: Column(
      children: [
        // Display the data loaded from sample.json
        _items.isNotEmpty
            ? Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: _items.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Card(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: ListTile(
                        leading: Text(_items[index]["aaaaa"]),
                        title: Text(_items[index]["aaaaa"]),
                        subtitle: Text(_items[index]["aaaaaa"]),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              )
            : Container()
          ],
    ),
  ),
);}
```